# Is it beneficial to use the same SSID & password for my router acting as an access point?

Tags: router, ssid, bridge-router

I have my main router downstairs, and have an ethernet cable running from my main router to my upstairs router which is acting as a bridge/accesspoint.

Should I configure my access point router to use the same SSID and password as my primary router? The only benefit I'm aware of is that is simplifies the initial connection process since there is only one option.

But sharing the same SSID/password vs using different SSIDs should not aid in my iPhone's ability to more quickly swap to the stronger signal right? And with different SSIDs, I can manually swap if I want to.

Comment: Having the same SSID offers little benefit, since there is no requirement, for both access points to have the same password.  You should look into routers that support the concept of a mesh network.  The basic idea behind them is the routers themselves handle the handoff.

Comment: @Ramhound I clarified I meant same SSID and password in post. I’m assuming your recommendation doesn’t change though.

Comment: Yes;  I would highly recommend a `801.11ax` (WiFi 5) mesh network.  Some of the name brand routers can create their own mesh network, there are other devices, specially called a "mesh network" but they all function nearly identical.

Comment: Actually I found this article which implies using the same SSID _does_ in fact speed up roaming between access points. https://www.smallnetbuilder.com/basics/wireless-basics/33180-how-to-fix-wi-fi-roaming

Comment: That article is only true if the router supports those additional standards which is basically what I suggested by using a router that supports mesh networks.  Some of what is described in that article also requires client support.  With zero information about your clients if you will actually see any benefit will be difficult to determine